# Maven doesn't find imported class from another module but Intellij does

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compilation, multi-module

I have multi-module maven project. The **acceptance-tests** module has dependency from **api** module in **pom.xml** (Replacing real company name by ***xxx*** to keep confidentiality). I am trying to import some classes from **api** module in my **acceptance-tests**.

Here is my **pom.xml** dependency of **acceptance-tests** module:

```
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>xxx-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
            <version>${xxx.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

The **api** module separately is being installed and packaged (**mvn install**, **mvn package**) by maven without any issue. The **jar** file is being created in my local **.m2**.

However, when I try to compile the **acceptance-tests** module, I get a compilation error saying that the the classes cannot be imported because the package is not found.

Here is the actual error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project xxx-acceptance-tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/andranik_chorokhyan/mydisk/Projects/XXX/automation/xxx-project-test-automation/xxx-acceptance-tests/src/main/java/com/xxx/xxx/utilities/api/ApiPayloadUtils.java:[17,38] package com.xxx.domain.dto does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/andranik_chorokhyan/mydisk/Projects/XXX/automation/xxx-project-test-automation/xxx-acceptance-tests/src/main/java/com/xxx/xxx/utilities/api/ApiPayloadUtils.java:[18,38] package com.xxx.domain.dto does not exist
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MappingData
[ERROR]   location: class com.xxx.utilities.api.ApiPayloadUtils
```

One more interesting fact is that there is no error visible in Intellij IDEA. No red underline, no compilation error, no problem with navigating to the appropriate imported file.
And in reality, the **com.xxx.domain.dto** package does exist and the **MappingData** class as well.

I removed whole **xxx** directory from my local **.m2** repository and executed `mvn clean dependency:resolve` command. It succeeded as well.

Does anybody know what's the problem here and how it can be solved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at `mvn dependency:list`. See which version is on the list. Open that version and see if the package indeed is in that jar.

Comment: Yes, it is. The **api** module dependency version's jar exists in my **.m2** repo

Comment: So have you opened the jar and looked whether it contains the `*.class` file that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have opened the ```BOOT-INF/classes``` directory and found the appropriate ```class``` file by the expected package path

Comment: The class should not be in a subdirectory. Note that you should not construct dependencies to executable jars like those from Spring Boot.

Comment: Ah so you have a spring boot app package as a dependency which does not work...so it's not an reusable API it's an application

Comment: Yes, but technically it's a jar, right? Why I can't have a dependency from it?

Comment: Because it puts the classes under `BOOT-INF` and not into the main directory.

Comment: Hm, got it. So, even if that's a module in my project, I am not able to use it's classes in another module.
But why the IntelliJ Idea does not catch the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. Thanks [JF Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/jf-meier) and [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) for hints.

It appeared Maven doesn't allow dependency from executable jar. This was my case. My **api** module was an executable **Spring Boot** application and not reusable library.

So, the solution was the following:

1. It was necessary to find the `Application.java` file in `api` module.
2. Add `maven-jar-plugin` with exclusion of the `Application.java` file and specification of some classifier
3. Making dependency in `acceptance-tests` module from the above specified classifier instead of standard jar

Plugin specification in **api** module below:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>qa</classifier>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/Application*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Dependency in **acceptance-tests** module below:

```
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>xxx-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
            <version>${api.version}</version>
            <classifier>qa</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You shouldn't add the jar plugin just to exclude it. If you don't want an executable jar then dont import the plugin the builds it.

Answer (score 11):

I was also getting symbol not found errors while compiling with maven, and the solution is for spring boot 2 you need to configure plugin as below, **[classifier exec](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-classifier)**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

If you are working with spring boot 1

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` when you `install/deploy` repackages your project and places it into a local/remote repository, this jar file cannot be used as a library, according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging.examples.local-artifact) you should configure the plugin to install/deploy only the original jar file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Spring-boot-maven-plugin** should be removed from the **pom.xml** inside the library, because there is no need to build an executable jar for a Library project.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

see more details in [multi-module](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)